# Do I need to have a website in order to get twitter API auth keys?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

My goal is to download all of the tweets of a particular user.

I tried to download them by using the web interface, but it seems that it gives me less than 1000 tweets.

I found that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471489/find-all-tweets-from-a-user-not-just-the-first-3-200) implies that there is a method for downloading tweets up to 3200. But the OP was unhappy about the limit of 3200, and wanted to go beyond that.

However, I'm for now happy with the 3200 tweets limitation. But my question what is the simplest method get authenticate keys to use the twitter API.

Comment: What language are you using?  3200 sounds like a pretty low limit (think Kim Kardashian who probably tweets that amount in under a week).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Python, and I use exactly this script https://gist.github.com/yanofsky/5436496